# What time was my Xbox 360 switched on?

Tags: xbox-360

Last night, somebody stole one of my Xbox 360 wireless controllers, switching my Xbox on in the process.  It would be helpful to know what time my Xbox was switched on, as that would tell me (and the police!) what time the burglery occured.  The Xbox is still on, sitting at the dashboard.  Is there any was I can see how long I've been idle for?  Can my friends see this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Even though I now have the rough time that my Xbox was switched on, it would be useful if I could see the exact time.  Is there a way to see the last few times you logged onto Xbox Live?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Xbox Live or Windows Gaming tech support: http://support.xbox.com/en-gb/pages/call-us.aspx / http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Support/Pages/contactsupport.aspx - they have UK freephone numbers.

Comment: I phoned them and they're checking the logs for me.  If you want to repost your comment as an answer then I'll probably end up accepting it.

Comment: Microsoft didn't get back to me :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that your friends can see how long you've been online for, roughly - "Username - idle for seven hours".

Comment: Probably could get it exactly if you waited til it turned over between hours.

Comment: Possibly.  The only thing there is that it was showing how long I'd been idle for - was I idle from the minute my console was turned on or did a certain amount of time, not included in the idle time, pass first?  I might have to experiment with this...

Comment: Emm, it usually from an hour on wards I've noticed but I think it's from 30min+